# What should I pass for the WWW-Authenticate header on 401s if I'm only using OpenID?

Tags: http, authentication, openid, http-headers

The HTTP spec states:

> **10.4.2 401 Unauthorized**
>
> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate
>   header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.

If the only login scheme I support is OpenID (or CAS, or OAuth tokens, &c.), what should I put in this field? That is, how do I indicate that the client needs to *pre-authenticate* and create a session rather than try to send credentials along with each request?

Before you answer, "don't send a 401; send a 3xx redirecting to the OpenID login page," what about for non-HTML clients?  How, for example, would Stack Overflow do an API that my custom software could interact with?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [RFC2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-1.2) the `auth-scheme` can be anything; if you really want a 401 you're not *technically* breaking spec by making something up like `WWW-Authenticate: OpenID realm="My Realm" location="http://my/login/location"`. Having said that, behaviour of other people's code when you do that is of course undefined. :-)

Comment: Updated by [RFC 7235](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-4.1).

Answer (score 3):

There is an [OAuth Discovery spec](http://oauth.net/discovery/1.0/) that would indicate what to put into the WWW-Authenticate header -- if the spec were not obsolete without a replacement spec yet.