# Securing Mobile app access to a WebService (home-grown approache)

Tags: iphone, web-services, security, authentication, oauth

I have an `HTTPS` WebService that need to be accessed from a Mobile (iPhone) application. both are developed by our-side.

We need to secure the Mobile access to this Service. So we used a username/password credentials.

We are aware of [OAuth](http://oauth.net/), but we need a more simple authentication scheme.

What We think of is the following:

1. The **Mobile** App shows a Login-form to the **User/Resource Owner**.
2. The **Resource Owner** enter The login credentials on behave of the **Mobile** App.
3. The **Mobile** app connect to the **Server** at special WS Method (e.g. "ValidateLogin") that takes username/password -probably hashed- as input and returns the `HTTP Session Id`.
4. The **Mobile** app *persists* this `HTTP Session Id` -which is a unique key from server side, and may be secure?- to communicate with the **Server** for subsequent requests (Invoking business methods).
5. If the **Client** doesn't communicate with the **Server** for say 30 Min, the **Server** will send [403/Session_time_out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653493/what-http-status-code-is-supposed-to-be-used-to-tell-the-client-the-session-has) (The **Mobile** may remove the persisted `HTTP Session Id` to indicate to himself that he no longer has access to the **Server** resources - and It may opt to do so in case if it needs to end the communication with the **Server**)
6. In this case, the **Mobile** will need to use the **Resource Owner** again to obtain a new session id from the **Server** and gain access to the **Server** resources.

---

**The Questions are:**

- Does the above steps are good enough to depend on?
- What do you think from security perspective?
- Do you have any other thoughts/opinions?

`EDIT`: It is a HTTPS WebService

Comment: I think I gonna implement it http://code.google.com/p/smauth/

Answer (score 0):

The question is very open in nature, and I believe that it is difficult to answer those general questions with your specific needs in mind.

To answer some concrete questions:
*How to secure your app against unauthorized clients?*
Look at SSL and [Client side certificates](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/securitymonkey/howto-securing-a-website-with-client-ssl-certificates-11500).

*How to manage user credentials securely?*
Look at using the [Keychain API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) in iOS.

Comment: Just curious: Do you mean that some part of my answer does *not* relate to HTTPS?

Comment: No, I mean that I've already using HTTPS. `To answer some concrete questions: How to secure your app against unauthorized clients? Look at SSL and Client side certificates.`