# Grails Show Login Page when Session has Expired Asynchronous Request

Tags: session, grails, asynchronous, request

I'm building a web application in Grails.
All request coming from the view(s) are done in asynchronous way. Each controller return
a template using "render" construct.

I would like to show/forward the user to the login view when the session has expired.

(This is automatically done by grails when the request are performed in synch way).

How can I achieve this result ? Or how can I intercept the session timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Given the reference from [What http status code is supposed to be used to tell the client the session has timed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653493/what-http-status-code-is-supposed-to-be-used-to-tell-the-client-the-session-has) , I think a simple way to get session-expired access redirected to login page is adding to UrlMappings something like this:

```
"403"(view:'/login')
```

Comment: I had to insert this

"401"(controller:'/login')

and I have also the specified the controller in the redirect

created by Spring Security in this way:

def index = {
    log.debug "login index"
    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
       redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
    }
    else {
       redirect controller:'login' , action: 'auth', params: params
    }
}