# prevAll - how to get html instead object?

Tags: jquery, console, local-storage

```
<span class='spant'>sky</span>
<span class='spant'>sea</span>
<span class='spant'>earth</span>
<span class='spant'>moon</span>
```

js

```
$(document).on('click', '.spant', function () {
    var a = $(this).prevAll('.spant').addBack();
    console.log(a);
    localStorage.setItem('path', a);
});
```

click on span `earth`, for example.
console result:

```
[span.spant, prevObject: m.fn.init[0], context: span.spant]
```

localStorage result:

```
[object Object]
```

What I need is (console and localStorage):

```
<span class='spant'>sky</span><span class='spant'>sea</span><span class='spant'>earth</span>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` to create a string of the `outerHTML` of the matched elements, either using `get` to get a true array from the jQuery object:

```
var html = a.get().reduce(function(html, element) {
  return html + element.outerHTML;
}, "");
```

...or by using `reduce` *on* the jQuery object:

```
var html = Array.prototype.reduce.call(a, function(html, element) {
  return html + element.outerHTML;
}, "");
```

Example of the first:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.spant', function () {
    var a = $(this).prevAll('.spant').addBack();
    var html = a.get().reduce(function(html, element) {
      return html + element.outerHTML;
    }, "");
    console.log(html);
    //localStorage.setItem('path', html);
});
```

```html
<span class='spant'>sky</span>
<span class='spant'>sea</span>
<span class='spant'>earth</span>
<span class='spant'>moon</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you don't want to use `reduce`, a boring old loop:

```
var html = ""
a.each(function() {
  html += this.outerHTML;
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.spant', function () {
    var a = $(this).prevAll('.spant').addBack();
    var html = ""
    a.each(function() {
      html += this.outerHTML;
    });
    console.log(html);
    //localStorage.setItem('path', html);
});
```

```html
<span class='spant'>sky</span>
<span class='spant'>sea</span>
<span class='spant'>earth</span>
<span class='spant'>moon</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...which I can't help but notice is both shorter and easier to understand. ;-)

Comment: T.J. what do you think about **[my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38813672/1076753)**?

Comment: @Vixed: Sure, you can use a loop instead of `each`. I strongly suggest using Stack Snippets, not off-site resources.

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder This is unrelated to this question but do you know why the `.htaccess` file is "breaking" upon including certain `ErrorDocuments` as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811962/htaccess-breaks-upon-including-an-argument-for-http-451)?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
$(document).on('click', '.spant', function () {
    var a = $(this).prevAll('.spant').addBack();
    var b='';
    for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      b=b+a[i].outerHTML;
    console.log(b);
    localStorage.setItem('path', b);
});
```

Check this **https://fiddle.jshell.net/sjdxofxj/**