# Sending POST request via HTTP using Safari on Mac

Tags: json, macos, http, post, safari

I need to call a webservice with Safari on Mac. Since the methods are in POST I can't paste the url in the address bar of Safari (like with GET methods).

So, I'm looking for a plug-in or similar that allows me to send the request and then receive the response inside the browser. The response is JSON so with the JSON plug in I can see all the response with his formatting.

Solutions ? Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another great tool is [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), an application inside Google Chrome.

Answer (score 34):

Safari is my browser of choice, so I can empathize with you for wanting a native plugin.  Fortunately, while there aren't any extensions available, there are quite a few native OSX clients for HTTP/REST end-point testing.  I have been using CocoaRestClient, which includes auto-formatting and syntax highlighting for JSON, as you requested.  It's open source, lightweight, and is at least actively supported by its developers:

http://mmattozzi.github.io/cocoa-rest-client

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you care whether the client is in Safari or not. A restful POST should be able to be executed from any sort of client.  You might want to look at RESTClient extension for Firefox http://restclient.net/

Also just Google 'REST client' you should see plenty of other tools available to generate POST's against your service.  If you are really would about Safari-specific responses, most good REST tools, should allow you to set the User-Agent header so as to make the request look like it is coming from Safari.

Comment: I want use Safari because is my default browser and I've installed a JSON formatting plug in to read the code very simply

Comment: @Fry tools like RESTclient will also provide readable format JSON responses.

Comment: A good reason to use Safari is that it intercepts 401 AJAX responses, and testing the behaviour of a client-side application requires the use of Safari: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137611/how-to-prevent-safari-from-intercepting-401-responses-to-ajax-requests

Comment: or someone like me could have this problem :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018621/angularjs-headers-not-added-in-my-rest-using-safari

Comment: I tried to use RESTclient from FireFox on CentOS, but POST, PUT and DELETE requests are refused by server while GET and OPTIONS works fine. I am not sure it is the problem with the plugin, but just be aware.