# HttpUrlConnection not working and shows different status code for GET and POST call

Tags: java, android, exception, authentication, httpurlconnection

I am getting `FileNotFoundException` when making `GET` call to REST API. Here HTTP status code I get is `403`.

For `POST` call I get `IOException : No authentication challenges found`, whereas I pass `Authorization` header. Here I get HTTP status code `401`.

Look at my [already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121213/java-io-ioexception-no-authentication-challenges-found) to see the code and logcat screen shot for `POST` call.

Below I am attaching logcat screen shot for GET call :
[image]

**Note :** 
1) I have tried using `Authenticator`.
2) Tried different base64 flags such as NO_WRAP, URL_SAFE, DEFAULT.
3) My simple call to `www.google.com` works. 
4) When I log `urlConnection.getErrorStream()`, last line in image is printed. I don't understand what is that and what does it mean. I have specified `Content-type` to `application/json` in header.

**UPDATE :** I tried using `Burp` and found that headers "Accept", "Content-type" were different. I used the same as in iOS app. But still it does not work.

**Things to note :**
1) It always throws an Exception on the line `in = urlConnection.getInputStream();`.
2) I logged few things and according to it, content-length is 114, which is not null. content-type is `application/json; charser=utf-8`.

Comment: Maybe the server delivers a gzip (compressed) answer and the lib cannot read that stream.

Comment: @TeTeT Ok. I don't think that server sends a gzip because I use same API in iOS app where I get JSON response. And even if server sends it, why I get FileNotFoundException and "No authentication challenges found"? Any idea. BTW thanks.

Comment: I tried your code and all I got was `404 : Invalid requested action ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_REQUEST` for the URL `http://api.ridesharebuddy.com/rsmobile/user/`. Is it the good URL ?

Comment: @Raphaël That URL is not enough to make request. You have to set method to GET and pass 2 header which I have not shown in code as they have not anything related to the problem. By the way I solved the problem and going to put as an answer so that others with similar issue can try that.

Comment: I think Raphael is right

Comment: @bright I have solved my problem and you can it posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and it is something I never tried to focus on while solving the problem.

I need not pass `Authorization` header. The thing is that there are 2 credentials come into the picture. one is server's authorization and second is credentials for `login` API. In my app, user creates an account and login to it. To authenticate the user I pass credentials to server and server authenticate it.

So when user enters correct credentials then response received is correct. And, in case of wrong credentials, my server passes a error message `You are not authorized person`, which I want to display to user(as in my iOS app). So the problem is here that HTTP status code (in case of wrong credentals) is 401 and that is why I don't receive the message sent by the server (and receive `No authentication challenges found` message).

The reason why I don't receive server message is that `HttpUrlConnection don't give server response when HTTP status code is >= 400`.

The only option to get error details in case status code 400 and above is to use `getErrorStream()` method and using that I was receiving `No authentication challenges found` message.

Finally, either I had to handle each status code, that is equal and above 400, at client side or I can use `HttpClient`, instead of `HttpUrlConnection`. And now I am moving to `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between your HTTP traffic for iOS and for Android.  This is guaranteed, otherwise you'd get identical behaviour from the server.  The difference is probably in HTTP header(s) &/or parameter(s).

This is very difficult to debug remotely via SO Q&A - E.g. we don't know what headers & parameters your iOS client is successfully using nor how your server is configured & programmed.

How to diagnose the problem & correct yourself:

1. Trace your working HTTP traffic: iOS client  <->  server
2. Trace your non-working HTTP traffic: Android client <-> server
3. Compare (2) and (3).  For the most thorough comparison, save each HTTP request and response message as a separate file for (2) and (3), then `diff` the corresponding files.

Recommended HTTP tracing tools:

- [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) (windows only)  See also [Documentation](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddler)
- [Burp](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/downloadfree.html) (JVM-based: windows, linux, OSX, etc)   See also [Getting Started](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/help/suite_gettingstarted.html)
- [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project) (JVM-based: windows, linux, OSX, etc)  See also [Getting Started](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/WebScarab_Getting_Started)

**UPDATE**

Seems you have the same problem for both GET and POST:  the server is configured for BASIC authentication, but the client is not following the authentication protocol correctly.  I think it just shows as a slightly different sympton in the two cases: for GET it says 'resource not found' (because you're not authenticated) and for POST the resource is *given by you*, but the server says you're not authorized to change the resource on the server. I suggest you've done enough (good!) debugging of request contents and now you should stop and focus on getting authentication working.

1. Send you GET/POST request to the server *without* `Authorization` header
2. Allow the server to prompt you for authentication with a 401 response with an `WWW-Authenticate` header containing a challenge string (e.g. `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected"`  see [RFC 2617 HTTP Basic Authentication and Digest Authentication](http://repository.root-me.org/Exploitation%20-%20Web/EN%20-%20HTTP%20basic%20authentication%20and%20digest%20authentication.pdf))
3. Now send an additional GET request to server that (either without/with the original request contents), but includes the Authentication header, with Base 64 encoded username:password (`Authorization: Basic ZnJhbms6ZmllZGxlcg==`)

Comment: Good work.  Thanks.  :-)  Did you see a response message with Burp?

Comment: I just see request in Burp. Do I need to make any change in settings to see response? Thanks to keep helping.

Comment: I am able to look at response. It always times out with coe 408. Yesterday also when using proxy server I was having this problem. If I turn proxy server off then I never get timeout and get exception as described in my question.

Comment: When you see the Request message displayed, then on the Interception tab click Forward.  This sends the Request to the server, which returns the Response, which should then be displayed by Burp.

Comment: I had to make some changes in settings and I did that. Please look at my previous comment for update.

Comment: Ok.  When you pass the request through a Proxy, the Proxy may insert the Date.  If you then get 408, it would very likely be due to big clock time mismatch between Proxy and Server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32134/discussion-between-akash-and-glen-best)

Comment: As I posted in chat message that I tried with what your update says but still problem persists. Another important thing I came to know is that running the same code in another machine gave correct response without any exception. Do you have any idea what can be wrong  in this case? Thank you.

Comment: On one machine the same code works. May be on that machine it does not ask for authentication at all. Because pass `Authorization` header same way as shown in code.

Comment: To test whether you're authenticating correctly, create a test Servlet & debug by calling request.getRemoteUser() / getUserPrincipal() / isUserInRole().  If this doesn't work, forget everything else & make it work.

Comment: I just noticed that I don't even need to send my server authentication. So basically when user tries to login to my app, I call API to authenticate the user. when user enters correct details then I get response but when it is wrong then all this happens. So the whole question has changed now. Now, from client side it is ok but server side when wrong credentials are received, an exception is thrown and client side I should get that exception message. This happens with iOS app, but not in android.

Comment: So your app is not configured to use Basic Authentication?  Instead you're using Form-Based Authentication?  That's a significant difference.  Immediately remove all use of Authenticate header. Follow a tutorial on using Servlets with form-based authentication...  Make sure your Android app does login correctly before it does anything else.  Cheers.

Comment: I solved my issue. To see, take a look at my answer. BTW Thank you for help and explanation. +1 for it.

Comment: Fabulous.  Happy to help.  BTW: there definitely would have been a difference between iOS & Android traffic.  And the tracing & comparison would have shown that iOS did not use Authorization, but Android did. i.e. Think response above still stands. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and solved by passing the authenticated session cookie. Not sure if that is possible in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    AuthUser="foobar"
    AuthPass="password"
    URL targetUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    String authStr = Base64Variants.MIME_NO_LINEFEEDS.encode((AuthUser+":"+AuthPass).getBytes());
    connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+authStr);
    InputStream inputStream= connection.getInputStream();
```

I just run something like this and it worked perfectly for me. Just make sure you use **Base64Variants.MIME_NO_LINEFEEDS** and you should be able to create a proper authentication header. If that doesn't work, then you might have some problem on the server side.