# RetrofitError response is null on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit library in my Android project. I have a rest server and trying to make request to it's login method. If login failed, server returns me 401 error and detailed message in json. My problem is that on my Nexus 5 with Android 5.0 it works fine, I can get the response body from the RetrofitError object. But on other devices, such as Sony Xperia M with Android 4.2.2 on the same request I'm getting `No authentication challenges found` exception and the RetrofitError.response object is null. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code. I also use Robospice library.

So this is an interface:

```
@POST("/auth")
User logIn(@Body UserSignUp userSignUp);
```

Here is my Robospice request class

```
public class UserLoginRequest extends RetrofitSpiceRequest<User, Server> {

private UserSignUp userSignUp;

public UserLoginRequest(UserSignUp userSignUp) {
    super(User.class, Server.class);
    this.userSignUp = userSignUp;
}

@Override
public User loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    return getService().logIn(userSignUp);
}
}
```

And here is my request listener:

```
public final class UserLoginListener implements RequestListener<User> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        if (spiceException.getCause() != null && ((RetrofitError) spiceException.getCause()).getBody() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ((ResponseDto) (((RetrofitError) spiceException.getCause()).getBody())).error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //On Nexus 5 with Android 5 this line works fine
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //On other devices I'm getting to this
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(User user) {
        //Some code here
    }
}
```

`User` is a subclass of `ResponseDto` class. `ResponseDto` class has only one public string field called `error`.

Comment: can you paste the relevant code here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this exception is versions related - it's IOException thrown by HttpURLConnection. Try to change server's behavior or handle the IOException in retrofit.

> No authentication challenges found
>
> This error happens beause the server sends a 401 (Unauthorized) but does not give a WWW-Authenticate header which is a hint for the client what to do next.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534175/497132)