# Why do I get android java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found?

Tags: java, android

i wrote the following code to get the json string from the service which is protected by basic auth

```
  InputStream input;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    HttpURLConnection connection;
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("mail@mail.com:123123".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " + basicAuth );


                        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            return "server retured" + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                        }

                        input = connection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"), 8);
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                          sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return sb.toString();
```

this function return exception says No authentication challenges found

i see some people says you MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field

how to include it if it is the soltution ? or what is the correct solution?

and this is the stacktrace

```
04-20 13:31:19.830 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
04-20 13:31:19.930 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:427)
04-20 13:31:19.935 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
04-20 13:31:19.940 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:356)
04-20 13:31:19.940 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
04-20 13:31:19.940 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
04-20 13:31:19.940 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.computer.myapplication.MainActivity$3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:264)
04-20 13:31:19.945 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.computer.myapplication.MainActivity$3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:250)
04-20 13:31:19.945 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-20 13:31:19.945 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-20 13:31:19.950 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-20 13:31:19.950 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-20 13:31:19.950 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-20 13:31:19.950 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-20 13:31:19.955 32036-1110/com.example.computer.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-20 13:31:24.735 32036-32037/com.example.computer.myapplication D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K, 7% free 14712K/15751K, paused 170ms+16ms, total 258ms
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the stacktrace please :)

Comment: i add the stacktrace

Comment: I think you question is answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121213/java-io-ioexception-no-authentication-challenges-found

Comment: i know this post but im asking how i can achieve that

Comment: how do i add WWW-Authenticate to the connection in a proper way

Comment: any solution to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing problem in concatenation
i.e.

```
String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("mail@mail.com:123123".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);  
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " + basicAuth );
```

No need to bind "basic" with already encoded string (basicAuth).

Try to change with below code:

```
String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("mail@mail.com:123123".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);  
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth);
```

I hope it work.

Comment: wow the problem was the word Basic twice thanks man and sorry my eyes are not sharp any more to see it